# Fetch and display image in reactjs from django backend using json

Tags: json, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-fullstack

An image is used as default in imageField in model.py file.

```
from django.db import models
class Product(models.Model):
  item_title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
  item_desc=models.TextField()
  item_price=models.IntegerField()
  item_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',default='default.png')
```

Here is my serializer class

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields= ('item_title', 'item_desc', 'item_price', 'item_image')
```

And views.py is-

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = ProductSerializer
  queryset = Product.objects.all()
```

The json data received at localhost:8000 is
[localhost:8000/api/products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIuDY.png)

Getting data at frontend(react js) in App.js. Here is code

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productList: [],
    };
  }

  refreshList = () => {
    axios
     .get("/api/protducts/")
     .then((res) => this.setState({ productList: res.data }))
     .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.refreshList();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.productList.map((item) => (
          <Product key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
 }
 export default App;
```

And Product component at front end is

```
class Product extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
  return (
    <div class="jumbotron col-sm-2">
      <img src={this.props.item.item_image}></img>
      <mark>{this.props.item.item_title}</mark>
      <div class="lead">{this.props.item.item_desc}</div>
      <div class="text-primary">{this.props.item.item_price}</div>
    </div>
  );}}
  export default Product;
```

Displayed data at fronted doesn't show any image.
[localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87FlQ.png)

Comment: Have you used any custom axios instance? If not then your ```get``` request is being directed to ```localhost:3000/api/products/```.

Comment: get request is able to directed to localhost:3000/api/products/.

Comment: and data is able to display at frontend, from backend. Please refer to images given in liks in questions. I am only unable to display images. String data working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass the image using JSON. You need to convert it to either base64 or any encoding. Let me explain to you an easy way:

1. create a field in your model named `item_image_url`.

```
class Product(models.Model):
  item_title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
  item_desc=models.TextField()
  item_price=models.IntegerField()
  item_image=models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images',default='default.png')
  item_image_url = models.TextField()
```

2. Override the default save method in the `Product` class and host your image online to any image hosting websites like imgbb or aws. A sample code is given below.

```
def save(self):
        encodedString = base64.b64encode(self.item_image.file.read())
        data = {"key": os.environ.get("IMG_BB"), "image": encodedString.decode("utf-8")}
        uploadedImageInfo = requests.post("https://api.imgbb.com/1/upload", data=data)
        jsonResponse = json.loads(uploadedImageInfo.text)
        self.item_image_url = jsonResponse["data"]["display_url"]
        super().save()
```

3. Now, in your serializer class, add `id` field for proper rendering in react and one more field `item_image_url` which will contain the URL of the image hosted on imgbb.

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Product
    fields= ('id', 'item_title', 'item_desc', 'item_price', 'item_image_url')
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need any further clarification.